# Possible to recursively serve an existing SVN checkout folder to another computer?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

For various reasons - We have "the-one" windows computer that has access to a svn repo. This svn repo is located on a separate svn server machine and this server/svn is not accessible to any other computer, from either the intranet or internet.

Said "the-one" computer has tortoise SVN and pulls stuff from the repo via 'svn checkout'.

We also have linux, windows/cygwin and macos boxes on the same local network. Unfortunately none of them can mount the "the-one" windows computer as a shared drive, although they all individually have rsync installed on them.

We would like to be able to share/serve this 'the-one' tortoise SVN folder as a master SVN repo to people working on these other computers.

Eventually, we will commit these changes back from other-people => 'the-one' => svn repo weekly.

Is this recursive serving of SVN checked out files possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you ask for is not possible with Subversion.

Subversion is a *centralized* version control system. Centralized means there's one repository to which clients connect. The repository consists mainly of a database which contains all the content and the history of the changes. These are stored in a binary, optimized format.

In contrast to that, any client has a *working copy* which contains (part of) the content, where the repository can be found and the last synchronized state of the local content as it would be found in the repository. Working copies usually contain textual data like source code and configuration files.

Long story short: repositories and working copies are not the same and you cannot use them interchangeably.

In your question, you do not explain where the repository resides. Is it also on "the-one" PC? If so, it should probably run a Subversion server to which clients can connect. It is also possible to copy an entire Subversion repository, e.g. through the `svnadmin` commands. This allows you to set up a repository in a more convenient location.

If you really want to share a working copy between several contributors, note that nothing will prevent them from overwriting each other's changes. This defeats the purpose of using a VCS. You would need to put another means of version control in place.

It may be tempting to consider `git svn` which creates a Git repository connected to a Subversion repository as an intermediary. Note however its [documented caveats](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#_caveats).

As for the `rsync` approach, that's essentially a very basic implementation of your own little VCS. I would not recommend it. Anyway, it might work until you run into trouble because ...

- conflicting changes to the same file
- timestamps are off
- added/deleted files are not propagated correctly
- anything else I can't foresee off the top of my head

In any case, I'd advise to `rsync` only the content, not the metadata. That means ignoring the `.svn` directory in the working copy. We would not want to rewind the working copy to an earlier stage because somebody `rsync`'d last month's `.svn` dir back (which should be fixed with an `svn update` but better to prevent these things in the first place).

FWIW, I've used `unison` (which is essentially a two-way `rsync`) for some rudimentary backup tasks. You might find it useful. I would still recommend to use a real VCS over a homegrown solution.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! I've edited the post above to clarify that the svn repo/server is on a different machine and this machine is only accessible the "the-one" computer on our network.

could we use rsync to share/sync the svn folder between "the-one" computer and the same svn folder on other computers ? We can internally guarantee that only 1 user would rsync "the-one" computer at a time and merge conflicts between users are *never* to be an issue,

Comment: @javadesigner I added a paragraph or two about your rsync idea. Sorry for not being overly optimistic. I've probably spent too much time in the inner workings of various VCS's.

Comment: Thanks again for the followup! I've played with rsync and it is working well for the moment. I'm exlcuding all metadata (including the .svn directory), via the handy rsync --cvs-exclude flag and --exlude options! I'll also checkout unison as per your suggestion.